# Wordpress : HTML code to insert before and after a custom posts type loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm blocked with an issue on wordpress and I need your help.

On my homepage, I would like to display a list of custom posts types (FAQ). For that, I used the widgets tool (wp-admin/widgets.php) with a widget Post loop (which seems to be added by the SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle plugin) and an associated template (path : /wp-content/themes/construction-field-pro/template-parts/) for the display of the different FAQ items.

The issue is that I should call HTML before and after that loop items and I never success it. I tried by 2 ways :

1 - by adding HTML widgets before and after the loop but WordPress is blocking the save as HTML end tags or start tags are missing.

2 - by adding short codes (which contains the desired html) before and after the loop. Saving is possible in that case but, at rendering, html end tags or start tags are added automatically which I do not expect.

So i need your help. How can I insert those loop items in an HTML blocks ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood this correctly, you are just trying to loop through your FAQs, which is a custom post type and to do this you have chosen to use widgets? Before and after the loop you are looking to add HTML code?

Why not just put the code directly into your homepage? Locate the place on the homepage you want the list to appear and enter:

```html
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'         => 'faq_post_type_name',
  'order'             => 'ASC',
  'orderby'           => 'date',
  'posts_per_page'    => -1
));


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <!-- Enter HTML before loop here -->
  <ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :$the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
  <!-- Enter HTML after loop here -->
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi devHensh,

Thank you for your answer but I don't think it's possible as I use widget for my HP and not only for this FAQ block : https://www.screencast.com/t/tVSxebWp

Am I Wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Newty, I never really use widgets, so I'm not sure I can help here. Theres no wrong way of doing it, but if you have access to the code, for FAQs, I would firstly suggest ACF Repeater field and if not that, then you could go down the Custom Post route. Hopefully you find an answer!

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution by adding the possibility to add php code in text fields.